# Artifacts while drawing quads

Tags: opengl

I am currently drawing some geometry with "modern OpenGL" using `QUAD` and `QUADSTRIP` primitives.

I have faced with strange artifacts. My quads actually tessellates with visible triangles. Hope you'll see while lines across quads.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit most likely is that you enabled polygon smooth antialiasing (still supported in compatibility profile), i.e. did `glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH)` + some blending function. Artifacts like the one you observe are the reason, nobody really bothered to use *that* method of antialiasing.

However, it may very well be, that you did enable antialiasing in your graphics driver settings and the AA method used doesn't play along nicely with your program.

Comment: great! I simply remove glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) and now it works like a charm :) thanks!

Comment: @frankie: Note that if you want antialiasing you should use multisampling FSAA. See https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Multisampling

Answer (score 4):

Modern OpenGL (3.1+ Core Profile) does not support QUADS or QUADSTRIPS. Check for example [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) for allowed primitive types.

Comment: But why I am still able to draw them?

Comment: @frankie legacy and backward compatibility

Comment: @frankie: Most likely you've got a compatibility profile.